# Getting enum name from enum instance

Tags: programming, c++, variables

Hello Arduino Stack Exchange,

I have an an `enum` instance called `state`:

```C
enum States
{
  SLEEP,
  AWAKE,
  CRAZY
} state;
States state = SLEEP;
```

I would like to convert the value of `state` to a `String` so I can serially print it using `Serial.println()`.

Currently, when I type `String(state)`, I get a value `0`, `1`, etc.  I suppose this corresponds with the index of the `enum`'s key.

How can I get it to return `"SLEEP"`, `"AWAKE"`, etc.?

Comment: your question is unrelated to the Arduino ... it is a C++ question ... please do some research about enums and about arrays

Comment: Will do @jsotola, thanks!

Comment: the `arrays` is a hint towards the solution

Comment: `States state = IDLE;` will not compile :)

Comment: Ah shoot @DataFiddler thanks for pointing that out.  My actual code has more `enum` cases, `IDLE` was one of them.  I updated the question to remove it

Comment: and did you read my answer?

Comment: Yes I had already read it, finally got around to testing it.  Thank you @Juraj

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can print the value as it is:

```
Serial.println(state);
```

This will print the the ordering number of the enum, but you can specify the value as any number **or char**.

```
enum States
{
  SLEEP = 'S',
  AWAKE = 'A',
  CRAZY = 'C'
};
```

Now if you print it with cast to char `Serial.println((char) state);` it will print a character, which in my opinion is much better then some number.

If you want to convert the enum values identifiers to strings you can do it with a preprocessor macro.

```
enum States
{
  SLEEP,
  AWAKE,
  CRAZY
} state;

#define IDNAME(name) #name
const char* stateNames[] = {IDNAME(SLEEP), IDNAME(AWAKE), IDNAME(CRAZY)};
```

I don't think this is better then to print the char values. To do a pretty print it is better to use descriptions.

```
const char* stateStr[] = {"Sleep", "Awake", "Undefined"};
Serial.println(stateStr[state]);
```

Comment: Love it.  Took me a minute (coming from Python) to realize `#name` wasn't a comment.  I used the preprocessor macro method, thank you!